# RGB565 color space bits order

Tags: colors, rgb

I am confused on RGB565 and BGR565 color space in bits order. e.g, the hex value 0xF81E, I don't know at RGB565, R is high 5 bits in (0xF81E & 0xF800), or R is low 5 bits (0xF81E & 0x001F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 16-bit value, then in RGB565 the R component will be the most significant 5 bits (ie high bits), whereas in BGR565 it'll be the least-significant 5 bits (low bits).

That said, if you are reading such 16-bit values from serialized bytes (eg a raw dump to file), then also consider the byte order of the serialization.  For example, if the serialization isn't big-endian (network byte order), then `0xF81E` appearing in adjacent raw bytes might indicate RGB565 value `0x1EF8`.